# awk not changing numbering in output file

Tags: awk

The below `awk` is supposed filter `$8` of the tab-delimited `input` using each line in `gene`. Then number each line skipping the header, sequentially. I think it is filtering the `input` but not numbering correctly. The desired output is just the filtered `input`  but with `$1` or `R_Index` sequentially numbered. Thank you :).

**input**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene
11  chr1    1147422 1147422 C   T   exonic  TNFRSF4
12  chr1    1168180 1168180 G   C   exonic  B3GALT6
```

**contents of gene**

```
TNFRSF4
B3GALT6
```

**current output** `---- header row---`

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene ---
11  chr1    1147422 1147422 C   T   exonic  TNFRSF4
12  chr1    1168180 1168180 G   C   exonic  B3GALT6
```

**desired output**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene
1   chr1    1147422 1147422 C   T   exonic  TNFRSF4
2   chr1    1168180 1168180 G   C   exonic  B3GALT6
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} FNR==1 || ($8 in a)' gene input | awk '{split($2,a,"-"); print a[1] "\t" $0}' | cut -f2-> output
```

Comment: You are just trying to output all the lines from `input` that have a value from `gene` in field `$8` to the output with sequentially numbered initial fields?

Comment: Your second `awk` script adds a leading field to the original lines and then the `cut` strips that field back off. (That's effectively a no-op.) Does field `$2` ever contain a `-` in your real data? It doesn't in your sample.

Comment: Since the data can be in different formats in `$2`, sometimes with a `-` I added that line just to be safe.  I apologize `$8` is the field in `input` that will possible contain the match to a line in`gene` value.  Thank you :).

Comment: sorry, R_Index is 1 then 2 then 3.... Thank you, I will edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but this MIGHT be what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} FNR==1{print} $8 in a{$1=++c; print}' gene input
```

Comment: This assumes `gene` has one gene per-line. If not then using the OPs loop in the `NR==FNR` block is correct but the rest of this in either case.

Comment: The sample input the OP posted DOES have 1 gene per line. If that's not what they really have then they need to provide more truly representative input. Obviously you can't figure out what needs to be done by reading a script the OP has told us doesn't do what needs to be done.

Comment: Agreed, the question was entirely not clear enough. I just wanted to point out the one piece of this answer that was materially different from the OPs attempt and was orthogonal to the problem being solved (in case it did matter to the OP, etc.).